# Can getUserMedia be used with Android's IP Webcam?

Tags: android, webrtc, webcam

I'm going through the WebRTC tutorial, and trying to setup their sample code.
Problem is, i do not have a webcam. I quickly realized that my Android phone can be used as a webcam using an App called IP Webcam, which transmits the video via wifi to my computer(which can be viewed in a special address).

Is there anyway, that this can be recognized and used by getUserMedia?

I'm using this sample code from he tutorial:
https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/webrtc-web/#3

When i run it, i get this error:

> code: 8 message: "Requested device not found" name: "NotFoundError"

Is there any way to make WebRTC aware of the connected phone?

I'm using Windows 7, latest Chrome, and serving the sample code via Xampp(if any of it matters)

Comment: Only if you can find a way to register the device with the system. I couldn't fine one, this was an interesting read though: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/10/media-devices

Comment: You can do all the WebRTC tricks on your Android device, you don't need to pass the video to PC for that